# Bootstrap multiple or single modules based on URL in main.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with a (.NET Framework MVC) web project that cannot be fully transferred to a full angular project, so I cannot use angular's routing to lazy load, but I also don't want to load everything where the angular components are used. It is an enterprise solution where it is not easy (and cheap) to say: "Hey, lets fully utilize angular and forget about the old project!".

So I have solved this, in my opinion, in a clean way to load different modules based on URL, to avoid loading everything all together:

**main.ts**

```
console.log("bootstrapping start");
if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("contactplans/details")) {
    console.log("bootstrapping contactplan details");
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ContactplanDetailsModule)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
} else if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("contactplans/index") || window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().endsWith("contactplans") || window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("settings/contactplans")) {
    console.log("bootstrapping contactplan index");
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ContactplanListModule) //contact plan index and settings page
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
} 
console.log("bootstrap decision done, bootstrapping menu");
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MenuModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

So based on the URL, it loads modules and on every page it loads the menu module.

For the time being, I kind-of have to do it this way, this is just a small example the the usage of angular will grow significantly on more and more individual pages until we can more easily 'switch' to a full angular project (within .NET Core which works awesome together).

So, this works fine on **development**. Using `ng build --watch` does the desired things.
Now going production, running `ng build --prod` it creates issues. To me it looks more like a **bug** then something else.

In the below screenshot I demonstrate what is being produced after `ng build --prod` when I make modifications to above code.

[Click here to show bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dhl0.png)
[image]

So as you can see, when only using one line of bootstrap, it works fine, no errors.

But when I have multiple like I want to have, it changes the actual Module to `function() {}` which then gives the console error:

`Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'function(){}'.`

Is this really a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I did the same I got this warning when I run ng serve . ```
WARNING in Lazy routes discovery is not enabled. Because there is neither an entryModule nor a statically analyzable bootstrap code in the main file.
```

Comment: Hi CularBytes, 
did you find the solution for this problem ? which approach you have taken? please suggest.

Comment: @kaleshanagineni unfortunately I couldn't find a better solution then the only answer there is.

Answer (score 2):

### Bootstrapping component based on url

I had the same problem, my solution was to bootstrap different components based on the url rather than bootstrapping different Modules

The solution is based on this article: [How to manually bootstrap an Angular application](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-manually-bootstrap-an-angular-application-9a36ccf86429)

You don't edit the main.ts but in the AppModule you bootstrap the different components manually based on the url and add them to the DOM

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ContactplanDetailsComponent } from './ContactplanDetails.component';
import { ContactplanListComponent } from './ContactplanList.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './Menu.component';



@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [
     ContactplanDetailsComponent,
     ContactplanListComponent,
     MenuComponent
  ],
  //bootstrap: [AppComponent] Bootstrapping is done manually
  entryComponents: [
     ContactplanDetailsComponent,
     ContactplanListComponent,
     MenuComponent
  ]

})
export class AppModule { 
  ngDoBootStrap(app) {
    bootstrapComponent(app);
  }
}

function bootstrapComponent(app) {

  var name = [];

  const options = {
    'contact-plan-details': ContactplanDetailsComponent,
    'contact-plan-list': ContactplanListComponent,
    'menu': MenuComponent
  };

  if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("contactplans/details")) {
    name.push("contact-plan-details"); 
  } else if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("contactplans/index") || window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().endsWith("contactplans") || window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("settings/contactplans")) {
    name.push("contact-plan-list");
  } 
  name.push("menu")

  name.forEach(function (element) {

    const componentElement = document.createElement(element);
    document.body.appendChild(componentElement);

    const component = options[element];
    app.bootstrap(component);

  });
}
```

Comment: Although it is in some way a valid answer, I unfortunately notice that it requires me to import all modules that every component needs. So I am not 100% sure if this would benefit loading time / performance. For example a html editor is imported into AppModule while it is only needed in the `ContactplanDetailsComponent`. What do you think?